# Python Linking Variable Values

Tags: python, variable-assignment

I want to to store a reference to a class object inside a dictionary or another class that will maintain the same value as the actual class object. Currently, I'm using a string of the class object and the eval() function. I know this isn't a proper solution but haven't found another fix.

- curWeapon is a object of WeaponInfo with pveFlag and pvpFlag variables
- ListSetting stores the boolean expression of curWeapon along with a,b,c...
- wishLists is passed to the main class of the program which reads a file and changed the pve/pvpFlags
- When a empty line is read the boolean expression is evaluated with the new flags

`wishLists.append(ListSetting("curWeapon.pveFlag or not curWeapon.pvpFlag", a, b, c, d))`

My only idea is making a new function that has separates the boolean expression from a,b,c.. when making the ListSetting and adding that separately. Although I'm not sure if wishLists would update the firstFlag, secondFlag... variables.

```
firstFlag = ListSetting(a,b,c,d)
wishLists.append(firstFlag)

def wishListFlags():
    firstFlag.flags = curWeapon.pveFlag or not curWeapon.pvpFlag
    secondFlag.flags = ""
    ...
```

I'm pretty sure that updating the index of wishLists would work but would need a bunch of if statements or a dictionary.

```
firstFlag = ListSetting(a,b,c,d)
wishLists.append(firstFlag)

flagExpressions = {
    1 : curWishListcurWeapon.pveFlag or not curWeapon.pvpFlag,
    2 : "",
    ...}

def wishListFlags():
    for index in len(wishLists):
        wishLists[index].flags = flagExpressions.get(index)
```

If anyone knows a better way to go about this please let me know. Also, if my examples aren't specific enough or are confusing I'd be happy to share my entire program, I didn't know if it would be too much.

Comment: Just put the class instance in the dictionary. That's a reference to the object.

Comment: Sorry can you explain more? Are you talking about the flagExpressions dictionary and what class instance would I put inside it? Also would I need to use that value in any way? Sorry for all the questions, I don't know much about Python. @Barmar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To store an expression you use a function, which you later call to get the value of the expression.

```
flagExpressions = {
    1: lambda: curWishListcurWeapon.pveFlag or not curWeapon.pvpFlag
    2: lambda: ""
}

def wishListFlags():
    for index in len(wishLists):
        wishLists[index].flags = flagExpressions.get(index, lambda: None)()
```

Comment: Thank you! I haven't seen lambda before but that's exactly what I needed.

Comment: I just updated my program and works perfectly. Thank you again, I was banging my head into a wall for the past couple of days.